# ак:Изменение аттрибутов тега, replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

На странице есть ссылки.

Нужно в аттрибутах ссылок удалить начальный и конечный слэш trim($str, '/'), изменить слэши на дефис(которые в пути ссылки), и добавть .html...

Не пойму как сделать, пытаюсь регулярнымы выражениями сделать, но не получается.

```
<p>
    <a title="fdfds" href="/contact/us" target="_self">click here</a>
    <a href="/back/us" title="fdsd" target="_self">click here</a>
</p>
```

Должно получится вот так:

```
 <p>
    <a title="fdfds" href="contact-us.html" target="_self">click here</a>
    <a href="back-us.html" title="fdsd" target="_self">click here</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще воспользоваться [парсером HTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) и там уже поменять что надо:

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$str = <<<DATA
<p>
    <a title="fdfds" href="/contact/us" target="_self">click here</a>
    <a href="/back/us" title="fdsd" target="_self">click here</a>
</p>
DATA;

$html = str_get_html($str);

foreach($html->find('a') as $link){
    $href = $link->href;

    $link->href = str_replace('/', '-', trim($href, '/')) . '.html';
}
```